# Why is std::shared_ptr::unique() deprecated?

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-ptr, c++17

What is the technical problem with `std::shared_ptr::unique()` that is the reason for its deprecation in C++17?

According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/unique), `std::shared_ptr::unique()` is deprecated in C++17 as

> this function is deprecated as of C++17 because `use_count` is only an approximation in multi-threaded environment.

<strike>I understand this to be true for `use_count() > 1`: While I'm holding a reference to it, someone else might simultaneously let go of his or create a new copy.</strike>

But if `use_count()` returns 1 (which is what I'm interested in when calling `unique()`) then there is no other thread that could change that value in a racy way, so I would expect that this should be safe:

```
if (myPtr && myPtr.unique()) {
    //Modify *myPtr
}
```

### Results from my own search:

I found this document: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0521r0.html which proposes the deprecation in response to *C++17 CD comment CA 14*, but I couldn't find said comment itself.

As an alternative, that paper proposed adding some notes including the following:

> Note: When multiple threads can affect the return value of `use_count()`, the result should be treated as approximate. **In particular, `use_count() == 1` does not imply that accesses through a previously destroyed `shared_ptr` have in any sense completed.** — end note

I understand that this might be the case for the way `use_count()` is currently specified (due to the lack of guaranteed synchronization), but why was the resolution not just to specify such synchronization and hence make the above pattern safe? If there was a fundamental limitation that wouldn't allow such synchronization (or make it forbiddingly costly), then how is it possible to correctly implement the destructor?

### Update:

I overlooked the obvious case presented by @alexeykuzmin0 and @rubenvb, because so far I only used `unique()` on instances of `shared_ptr` that were not accessible to other threads themselves. So there was no danger that that particular instance would get copied in a racy way.

I still would be interested to hear what exactly CA 14 was about, because I believe that all my use cases for `unique()` would work as long as it is guaranteed to synchronize with whatever happens to different `shared_ptr` instances on other threads. So it still seems like a useful tool to me, but I might overlook something fundamental here.

To illustrate what I have in mind, consider the following:

```
class MemoryCache {
public:
    MemoryCache(size_t size)
        : _cache(size)
    {
        for (auto& ptr : _cache) {
            ptr = std::make_shared<std::array<uint8_t, 256>>();
        }
    }

    // the returned chunk of memory might be passed to a different thread(s),
    // but the function is never accessed from two threads at the same time
    std::shared_ptr<std::array<uint8_t,256>> getChunk()
    {
        auto it = std::find_if(_cache.begin(), _cache.end(), [](auto& ptr) { return ptr.unique(); });
        if (it != _cache.end()) {
            //memory is no longer used by previous user, so it can be given to someone else
            return *it;
        } else {
            return{};
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::array<uint8_t, 256>>> _cache;
};
```

Is there anything wrong with it (if `unique()` would actually synchronize with the destructors of other copies)?

Comment: Why is 1 a special case? There might be another copy created after your call to `unique` and before you finish whatever you're doing.

Comment: @rubenvb: If `use_count == 1`, then there is - by defintion - no other thread that has a reference it could make a copy from.

Comment: @rubenvb: My mistake - unique is const, so another thread could make a copy without it being a data-race

Comment: `const` has nothing to do with it. If an object holding the shared_ptr is itself accessible from multiple threads, copies of the shared_ptr can be made regardless.

Comment: @rubenvb: If it wasn't const, then you'd have datarace when reading from the same instance simultaneously anyway

Comment: `const` doesn't prevent data races.

Comment: @rubenvb: IIRC, the standard library guarantees that as long as you only call const methods on an object, there will be no data races.

Comment: @MikeMB, I was about to answer to your update but I have seen that a sentence in the answer of alexeykuzmin0 almost answer your update. Your are right, If each of your thread only use copies of a shared_ptr then unique() will work fine. In the paper you cite and in the answer of alexykuzmin0 multiple thread share a reference to a unique shared_ptr... In the answer of alexeykuzmin0 the sentence "The `unique()=true` means that no one has a shared_ptr pointing to the same memory... may say almost the same thing no?

Comment: Of course `use_count` was not deprecated, so you can continue using `use_count()==1` so long as you remember it's racy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that [P0521R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0521r0.html) solves *potentially* data race by misusing `shared_ptr` as inter-thread synchronization.
It says `use_count()` returns unreliable refcount value, and so, `unique()` member function will be useless when multithreading.

```
int main() {
  int result = 0;
  auto sp1 = std::make_shared<int>(0);  // refcount: 1

  // Start another thread
  std::thread another_thread([&result, sp2 = sp1]{  // refcount: 1 -> 2
    result = 42;  // [W] store to result
    // [D] expire sp2 scope, and refcount: 2 -> 1
  });

  // Do multithreading stuff:
  //   Other threads may concurrently increment/decrement refcounf.

  if (sp1.unique()) {      // [U] refcount == 1?
    assert(result == 42);  // [R] read from result
    // This [R] read action cause data race w.r.t [W] write action.
  }

  another_thread.join();
  // Side note: thread termination and join() member function
  // have happens-before relationship, so [W] happens-before [R]
  // and there is no data race on following read action.
  assert(result == 42);
}
```

The member function `unique()` does not have any synchronization effect and there're no *happens-before* relationship from [D] `shared_ptr`'s destructor to [U] calling `unique()`.
So we cannot expect relationship [W] ⇒ [D] ⇒ [U] ⇒ [R] and [W] ⇒ [R]. ('⇒' denotes happens-before relationship).

---

**EDITED:** I found two related LWG Issues; [LWG2434. shared_ptr::use_count() is efficient](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/lwg/issue2434), [LWG2776. shared_ptr unique() and use_count()](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/lwg/issue2776). It is just a speculation, but WG21 Committee gives priority to the existing implementation of C++ Standard Library, so they codify its behavior in C++1z.

[LWG2434](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/lwg/issue2434) quote (emphasis mine):

> `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` have Notes that their `use_count()` might be inefficient. **This is an attempt to acknowledge reflinked implementations** (which can be used by Loki smart pointers, for example). **However, there aren't any `shared_ptr` implementations that use reflinking**, especially after C++11 recognized the existence of multithreading. Everyone uses atomic refcounts, so **`use_count()` is just an atomic load**.

[LWG2776](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/lwg/issue2776) quote (emphasis mine):

> The removal of the "debug only" restriction for `use_count()` and `unique()` in `shared_ptr` by LWG 2434 introduced a bug. In order for `unique()` to produce a useful and reliable value, it needs a synchronize clause to ensure that prior accesses through another reference are visible to the successful caller of `unique()`. **Many current implementations use a relaxed load, and do not provide this guarantee, since it's not stated in the standard.** For debug/hint usage that was OK. Without it the specification is unclear and probably misleading.
>
> [...]
>
> I would prefer to specify `use_count()` as only providing an unreliable hint of the actual count (another way of saying debug only). Or deprecate it, as JF suggested. **We can't make `use_count()` reliable without adding substantially more fencing. We really don't want someone waiting for `use_count() == 2` to determine that another thread got that far. And unfortunately, I don't think we currently say anything to make it clear that's a mistake.**
>
> This would imply that `use_count()` normally uses `memory_order_relaxed`, and unique is neither specified nor implemented in terms of `use_count()`.

Comment: That is actually an interesting point. Anybody who's using a shared pointer in the way your demonstration example does should probably get whipped, but there might be more complex patterns, where this assumption is made implicitly somewhere. I still would have preferred that they fix `unique()` by specifying a synchronization effect instead of deprecating it, but there might be performance implications that I don't see.

Comment: Thanks for digging up those comments

Comment: That is totally wrong: "so, unique() member function will be useless when multithreading". No, `unique()` is not useful for synchronization. That doesn't at all mean that it's "useless". I certainly hope you didn't really mean that, because then *everything* that cannot be used for synchronization would be "useless when multithreading".

Comment: It seems that there is no data race in [R] with [W] because sp1.unique() == true only when another_thread is finished. Thread working with a copy of sp1, so at least two references to a pointer are exist and sp1.unique() cannot be true while thread is running

Comment: @user3514538 Your interpretation about C++ atomics is wrong, read [LWG2776](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/lwg/issue2776).

Comment: C++ atomic `relaxed` access does not guarantee any ordering to another atomic access, even if they has control dependencies. For instance "[C11 atomic variables and the kernel](https://lwn.net/Articles/586838/)" explain similar situation.

Comment: `use_count()` and `unique()` are truly meaningless in the presence of `weak_ptr<>` because `lock()` may increase `use_count()` other than through a `shared_ptr<>` by creating a new one! So the assumption `sp.unique()==true` means `sp` has acquired **durable** single ownership is just false with weak-pointers in play.

Answer (score 11):

Consider the following code:

```
// global variable
std::shared_ptr<int> s = std::make_shared<int>();

// thread 1
if (s && s.unique()) {
    // modify *s
}

// thread 2
auto s2 = s;
```

Here we have a classic race condition: `s2` may (or may not) be created as a copy of `s` in thread 2 while thread 1 is inside the `if`.

The `unique() == true` means that no one has a `shared_ptr` pointing to the same memory, but does not mean any other threads have no access to initial `shared_ptr` directly or through pointers or references.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know, why I overlooked that obvious case. I still don't see why the function should be deprecated, but at least the decision makes more sense to me now.

Comment: I updated my question a bit. If you have any thoughts on it, please feel free to share.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer has so many upvotes. `s.unique() == true` was never claimed to mean that no other threads have access to `s`.

Comment: This is silly. Thread 1 could be executing *anything* that modifies `s` and this would be a race. This is nothing about `unique` and simply about the fact that you really don't want threads to share instances of `shared_ptr` but instead to each have their own instance that references the same underlying object.

Answer (score 4):

For your viewing pleasure: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0488r0.pdf

This document contains all NB (National Body) comments for the Issaquah meeting. CA 14 reads:

> The removal of the "debug only" restriction for use_count() and
>   unique() in shared_ptr introduced a bug: in order for unique() to
>   produce a useful and reliable value, it needs a synchronize clause to
>   ensure that prior accesses through another reference are visible to
>   the successful caller of unique(). Many current implementations use a
>   relaxed load, and do not provide this guarantee, since it's not stated
>   in the Standard. For debug/hint usage that was OK. Without it the
>   specification is unclear and misleading.

Comment: Thank you very much - I wonder why the commitee didn't take the comment's first proposed solution: *"A solution could make unique() use memory_order_acquire, and specifying that reference count decrement operations synchronize with unique()."*

Comment: @MikeMB I am afraid my searching did not uncover anything that might shed light on their motivation. The information may exist, but it's not a low hanging fruit.

Comment: The synchronization needed for this would pessimise some fairly common operations (like copying), to enable a (ab-)use of unique/use_count which was never intended anyway.

Comment: @FabioFracassi: can you go into a little more detail here? Afaik for unique to work in my example the refcount increment wouldn't have to synchronize with anything (teh decrement would however).

Comment: Not really, I did not attend that discussion.

Comment: @MikeMB Thread 1 stores the result of `getChunk` in `x`. Thread 2 copies `x` into `y`. Thread 1 destroys `x`. Thread 3 copies `y` into `z`. Thread 2 destroys `y`. The increment in thread 3 might not be seen by `unique` in thread 1.

Comment: @Oktalist:AFAIk, even relaxed loads on atomics preserve modification order and are not allowed to produce values out of thin air  (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Relaxed_ordering). There has to be a synchronization barrier between the increment in thread 3 and the destruction of y in thread 2, because otherwise you would have a data race on y anyway. Hence the increment happens before the decrement, hence the ref_count never falls below 2 (even from the perspective of thread 1).

Answer (score 1):

The existence of `std::enable_shared_from_this` is the trouble maker to make any
interesting use of `unique()`. Indeed, `std::enable_shared_from_this` allows to make a new `shared_ptr` from a raw pointer, from any thread. This means `unique()` can never be a guarantee for anything.

But consider another library... Though this is not about `shared_ptr`, in Qt, there is an **internal** method called `isDetached()` with (almost) the same implementation as `unique()`.
It is used for some quite useful optimization purpose: when `true`, the pointed object can be mutated without performing a "copy-on-write" operation.
Indeed, **once unique, a managed resource can't become shared by an action originating from another thread**. The same pattern would be possible with **shared_ptr** if **enable_shared_from_this** did not exist.

This is why IMHO, `unique()` has been removed from C++20: misleading.

Comment: This applies equally to any `weak_ptr` (which is what `enable_shared_from_this` ultimately stores), since `unique` doesn't count weak references as "uses".

Comment: I don't der the connection. Just because a object is managed by a shared_ptr doesn't mean it inherits from enable_shared_from_this.

Comment: @MikeMB: this is right, but I quote 'enable_shared_from_this' to justify that 'unique()' can't be a guarantee for anything, because the APIs from shared_ptr could alter the reference counter in different threads, both to increment or decrement.

Comment: Yes, and what I'm saying is that your argument applies to `std::shared_ptr<derived_from_enable_shared_from_this>` but not for any other `shared_ptr<T>`

Comment: I guess the main reason is that validity of `unique` does not even exceed the line within which `unique` is called; check in thread A, then suspend A, then increment in thread B, then suspend B and resume A; and this was not even concurrent.