# Make do without weak_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I found an example [here](https://www.nextptr.com/tutorial/ta1382183122/using-weak_ptr-for-circular-references) , about using an observer thread with an weak pointer:

```
std::thread observer;

void observe(std::weak_ptr<int> wp) {
 //Start observer thread
 observer = std::thread([wp](){
  while(true) {
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

   //Try acquiring a shared_ptr from weak_ptr
   if(std::shared_ptr<int> p = wp.lock()) {
    //Success
    std::cout << "Observing: " << *p << "\n";
   } else {
    //The managed object is destroyed. 
    std::cout << "Stop\n";
    break;
   }
  }
 });
}
```

But I was wondering why use a weak pointer?

The observer function could very much look like this, using a copy of the shared pointer through the function parameter:

```
void observe(std::shared_ptr<int> sp) {
 observer = std::thread([sp](){
  while(true) {
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

   if(sp.use_count() > 1) {
    //Success
    std::cout << "Observing: " << *p << "\n";
   } else {
    //The managed object is about to be destroyed. 
    std::cout << "Stop\n";
    break;
   }
  }
 });
}
```

So if the counter for the pointed object is 1 we know for sure that the dinamic object will be deleted when the function returns.

Comment: I'd rather see both the _before_ and _after_ code snippets presented in the question (as opposed to a link to the original).

Comment: We don't know for sure the object will be destroyed when the function returns. There could be a weak-pointer in another thread that locks the object while that function is executing. Trying to apportion meaning to use counts (outside the implementation that when it reaches 0 you delete the object, is the road to hell.

Comment: `But I was wondering why use a weak pointer?` To prevent strong reference cycle which will lead to memory leak. https://youtu.be/JfmTagWcqoE

Comment: For all the reasons it's a bad idea how about waiting for `use_count()` to reach 1 is a one trick pony. Two observer threads would be in a 'stand-off' both waiting for the other to release the object so they become the last owner!

Answer (score 2):

There's a useful and interesting discussion [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41142315/why-is-stdshared-ptrunique-deprecated) about possible data races introduced by `shared_ptr::use_count`, which was originally intended solely for use in debugging.

But leaving all that aside, consider what happens in your example when a second observer is independently added. Now, the use count never drops below 2 and the shared_ptr is never deleted. But the weak reference solution would continue to work, with no need for deep thought about potential races.

Perhaps in the initial design, a second observer was never contemplated. But that doesn't mean that it won't seem like a good idea at some point in the future

Answer (score 2):

In the provided first example the 'observer' polls (approx.) every second to see if the observed object **has** expired. That's because `wp.lock()` returns a shared-pointer to the object iff it has not expired (`wp.expired()==false`).

The comment `//The managed object is destroyed.` is not completely accurate. The object has expired and has been destroyed *or* some thread is about to or is in the process of destroying it - but it may not be destroyed.

So that slight inaccuracy aside the code works.

However the code proposed in the second example assumes that because the `use_count()` is 1 the `std::shared_ptr<int>` `sp` is "the last of it's kind" and when that shared-owner is destructed on return of the lambda-function then the object shall be destroyed.

**Not so in general.** There may be a `weak_ptr<>` referring to that object and if a call to `lock()` on that object happens after the call to `use_count()`(*) the use count will be increased to 2 and returning from the lambda-function (as the thread enters termination) will not cause the object to be destroyed.

The point here is that as soon as any `weak_ptr<>` returns `true` from `expired()` the object is in train to be destroyed and no valid use can obtain another `shared_ptr<>` to it.
But shared-pointers can be obtained from weak-pointers (if at least one shared-pointer remains).

See this note from C++ Reference on `expired()` which is quite telling (my emphasis):

> This function is inherently racy if the managed object is shared among
> threads. In particular, a false result may become stale before it can
> be used. **A true result is reliable**.

But while there is a `shared_ptr<>` any `weak_ptr<>::lock()` may succeed in a "lock" on the object and create a new `shared_ptr<>` but once the object is expired, it shall not / cannot be (somehow) reprieved.

This is a common feature of 'reference counting' designs.
The only truly reliable count is 0 - there's "no coming back from that".
If you don't implement weak-pointers you can with effort count references and work out if you can account for all the sharing owners.
But if you do implement weak-pointers that game is up.

If you then decide to start counting weak-pointers and making decisions about destruction based on them, well they're not weak-pointers anymore and that's a different game all together.

However do notice that reasoning about 'reference count' is a one trick pony. It only takes two observer threads (from the Question) to be in a deadlock where each is waiting for the other to release their ownership to destroy the object.
Some corner of code can play that game but it's not a reliable model for managing shared ownership.

**Footnote:**

I strongly advise against using `use_count()` for anything other than debugging because the only really meaningful return value is 0 and that is equivalent to `expired()==true` anyway.

IMHO `use_count()` is an uncommon error in the C++ Standard Library in which 'helper debug' members have been exposed and inevitably lead developers astray as well as nailing the class to a particular design which the Standard Library generally does not.

(*) Or is otherwise not reflected in the use count returned such as relaxed memory barriers regarding the count returned.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the [sharp edges of `use_count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/use_count#Notes) that make it *much* more difficult to use correctly than `weak_ptr`, your program does not behave the same as the initial example.

In your code the `shared_ptr` captured by the thread will keep the object alive as long as the observing thread is running. That means that in the worst case you will have to wait around 1 second after the last owner died before the observed object gets actually destroyed. Contrast that with the initial example where you would at most have to wait for the `weak_ptr` to release its copy, which is both much less likely to occur and has a much shorter expected effect on the lifetime of the object.

In case of an `int`, waiting one second for destruction might not seem like a big deal. But consider instead a more pathological example where the observed object executes a substantial operation in its destructor and the observer thread runs with a frequency of a single check per day...

Comment: Another issue is if the deleter held by the shared pointer has thread-affinity, e.g. in many gui libraries only the gui thread can delete widgets